# Heur.AdvML.B appears when .exe is generated from Ahk file

Tags: windows, autohotkey, symantec

I try to generate exe file from ahk project file. I use `Ahk2Exe v1.1.30.03_Beta_9`.

Ahk file, which should paste file path to browser's file chooser dialog window:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#Persistent

SetTimer, test, 500
return

test:

IfWinExist, Open
{
    WinActivate  ; Automatically uses the window found above.
    WinMaximize  ; same
    Send, ^v .{Enter}
    return
}
```

Symantec Endpoint Protection is blocking access to it with following reason:

> Scan type: Auto-Protect Scan Event: Security Risk Found! Security risk
>   detected: Heur.AdvML.B

Comment: Is there any reason you're compiling it to an executable? Maybe just install AHK and run your .ahk extension file? Or if you want to compile it for whatever reason, I can't say anything about that beta compiler you're using, maybe just install AHK and use AHK's own compiler (create an .ahk file and right click compile it)

Comment: @0x464e : I would like to execute it from Selenium WebDriver testscript to handle browser dialog window. Is it possible in other way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Selenium WebDriver. Could you try to explain the problem in a way so I can understand and maybe try to help.

Comment: @0x464e : I call an exe like this:            `String autoITExecutable = "C:\\_privat\\filechooser.exe \"" + fileSource + "\"";
            SECONDS.sleep(4);
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(autoITExecutable);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }` How could I do the same with an ahk file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using the ahk2exe pre-release ;)

Unless your system has been compromised, this is very likely a false positive.
You could try redownloading it, and compiling again:

- https://github.com/AutoHotkey/Ahk2Exe/releases/tag/1.1.30.03_Beta_9

That said, you can refer to the following documentation on AutoHotkey false positives:

- https://www.autohotkey.com/download/safe.htm
- https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#Virus
- https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=62266